# List of users by role, using fretje MvcMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So I've been meddling with this MvcMembership starter kit and so far this is the only troublesome part I've came across with...

Basically this membership uses `_userService` to gather data on users sorting them into `IPagedList`s.

User service:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    int TotalUsers { get; }
    int UsersOnline{ get; }
    IPagedList<MembershipUser> FindAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize);
    IPagedList<MembershipUser> FindByEmail(string emailAddressToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize);
    IPagedList<MembershipUser> FindByUserName(string userNameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize);
    MembershipUser Get(string userName);
    MembershipUser Get(object providerUserKey);
    void Update(MembershipUser user);
    void Delete(MembershipUser user);
    void Delete(MembershipUser user, bool deleteAllRelatedData);
    MembershipUser Touch(MembershipUser user);
    MembershipUser Touch(string userName);
    MembershipUser Touch(object providerUserKey);
    MembershipUser Create(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer);
}
```

And in controller it makes a readonly instance `private readonly IUserService _userService;`
Using it to gather data into a ViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<MembershipUser> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate it and pass the populated data to view.

```
return View(new IndexViewModel
                {
                    Users = _userService.FindAll(index ?? 0, PageSize),
                    Roles = _rolesService.FindAll()
                });
```

Now what I want is to filter users who share the same role as the current user. I got to role to a string but there's nothing to compare it with using Linq and when I try to make new ViewModel and use `IEnumerable<User>` then get desired data there I get all sorts of errors... Please help, I'm really really stuck...

**UPDATE**

```
public ViewResult Index(int? index)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("SUPER ADMIN GROUP"))
    {    
        return View(new IndexViewModel
                        {
                            Users = _userService.FindAll(index ?? 0, PageSize),
                            Roles = _rolesService.FindAll()
                        });
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Group Admin"))
    {
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        return View(new IndexViewModel
                        {
                            Users = (IPagedList<MembershipUser>)_userService.FindAll(index ?? 0, PageSize).Where(x => _rolesService.FindByUserName(x.UserName).SequenceEqual(roles)),
                            Roles = roles
                        });
    }

    return View();
}
```

This is my `Index` method. Basically I'm trying to limit accessibility of Group Admin to users that share his other role. For example a group admin has roles "Group Admin" and "Test", he would be able to see all users with "Test" role.

Getting user roles correctly isn't much of an issue. I just want this part to get right... If possible even..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using LINQ to keep only the users that have the same roles as the current user:

```
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
return View(new IndexViewModel
{
    Users = _userService
        .FindAll(index ?? 0, PageSize)
        .Where(
            x => _rolesService.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName).SequenceEqual(roles)
        ),
    Roles = roles
});
```

Comment: It says that `IEnumerable<string>` does not contain a definition for `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: Did you include `using System.Linq;` in order to bring LINQ into scope?

Comment: Of course. I have more than several Linq expressions on other action methods within this controller.

Comment: It seems that this query returns `IEnumerable<MembershipUser>` type when I need `IPagedList<MembershipUser>`. Also it says that explicit conversion is possible but implicit is not. Any ideas perhaps how to go around it with that?

Comment: Lastly, this is the error I got trying to cast it into `IPagedList`...
`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator 1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]' to type 'PagedList.IPagedList 1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]'.`

Comment: Where are you trying to do this cast? You haven't shown much of your code and I cannot read your mind.